# NextJS 13.4 Pass an handleSubmit function from a server component to client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

So basically I got my page.js skeleton using the default server component and return a reusable form component inside.

So I need the handleSubmit to be inside the page component and not inside the form component, so I can use the same form for multiple case by just passing different handleSubmit as props.

First it says I can't pass function as props to client component without the "use server", so I put it on the function.

But it doesn't work, when I submit the form I get errors such as `"Maximum call stack size exceeded"` or `"Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or other objects with methods are not supported."` or something else telling me to serialize something.

What I'm I supposed to do to pass an handleSubmit function from server to client component ?

It's supposed to be really basic stuff in react for reusability, and I can't get it to work unless it's in the client component.

export default async function PageServerComponent() {

```
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        "use server"

        e.preventDefault()

        try {
            await newProduct(datas)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return(<ReusableFormClientComponent handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />)
}
```

Comment: try 'datas.toString()'

Comment: or use `JSON.stringify(datas)`